# Mercurial - Rename/Merge Repository

Tags: mercurial, merge, rename

We use Mercurial and have set up a repo server to which all local/developer changes are pushed to/pulled from.  I came back from vacation to find that one of our repos has been replaced.  Apparently a developer was having issues pushing commits to it and figured the only solution was to blow away the repo on our server and push a new one from his machine under a new name.  Not sure how, but in doing this we lost all the change history of the project before it was blown away.

I still have the full repo history on my local machine up to that point and would like to merge the new repo with the old repo and have the full change history retained.  I'm hesitant to do a pull/update to my machine in case I lose the history.

I also want to update the name of the repo directory on the server because now some of our tools have broken paths to the repo and would prefer reverting back to the original directory name insted of updating all our tools' references.

I think I can use the `hg rename` to do what I want regarding the rename, but how do I merge the two repos into one?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to merge by following (somewhat) the instructions here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergingUnrelatedRepositories

- First I made a copy of my local repo in case things went sideways
- I cloned the repo on the server to the name I wanted it to be and which matched my local repo
- I did a pull on the server repo to my local one and instead of doing an update, did a merge
- Resolved merge diffs and committed locally
- Pushed changes to new server repo, confirmed full change history was in place
- Removed old server repo

Comment: You describe a very strange set of affairs; because if the past history of the repo was really missing from the server you found on your return, it should have been an unrelated repo and you would not have been able to merge from it. So it's not clear what problem you were dealing with there.